# Angular 2.0 - ES6 without typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

So on Angular 2.0 get started pages, it says that we can use Typescript for importing modules, but isn't that core part of ES6?

So, once ES6 will be fully supported (or at least module loading) ins browsers, does it mean we won't have to use Typescript in our Angular 2.0 applications?

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html "import vs. window.angular" chapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does it mean we won't have to use Typescript in our Angular 2.0 applications

Yes. If the module loader is natively supported you don't need typescript for module loading transpilation.

Fact: You don't have to use typescript even today.. you can write the JavaScript that typescript generates by hand or even use something else like babel.

Comment: And annotations? For that I would have to use typescript, or is that angular2.0 support?

Comment: ES7 : to es5 transpilers TypeScript / BabelJS / others  .... or write the javascript these transpile manually

Answer (score 3):

Basically using TypeScript in your Angular 2.0 or Angular 1.x helps you in development, with TypeDef your editor provides intellisense, and all almost all the features by ES6 is in TypeScript.